# DBLink Priveleges vs User Privileges

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have a user on `DB1` with only `SELECT` privileges.

I have a `DBLink` to `DB2` created on `DB1`.

What are the priveleges that the user will have on `DB2` tables? Do they depend on his priveleges on `DB2`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the syntax of a database link, the privileges one has with the database link are dependent on the database user which is being used
to connect with the database being linked.

For example, with the database link below, the apps database account is being used on the db2 database.

Thus whatever privileges are granted to apps@db2, system or object, these are the privileges which user1@db1, the owner of the dblink, has through this database link.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK user1.db1_to_db2.cm.big_company.com
  CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY VALUES apps_password USING '(DESCRIPTION=            
(ADDRESS_LIST=                
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname.cm.big_company.com)(PORT=1577))            
)            
(CONNECT_DATA=                
(SERVICE_NAME=db2)            
)        
)';
```

Comment: You mean that the user on `DB1` will have the same privileges than the user used to authenticate the `DBLink`?

Comment: Yes, as 11g documentations states here, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/ds_concepts002.htm.  Specifically look at the "Fixed user link" description.